# How to compile gcc parallel-mode STL code with nvcc?

Tags: gcc, stl, cuda, openmp, nvcc

I'm trying to compile a third-party library on my GPU with nvcc 5.5.0 but I keep getting a compilation error in the STL. I've tracked it down to the library's use of the GCC parallel headers. Specifically this is a minimal example that causes the compilation problem:

```
#include <parallel/algorithm>
```

This compiles fine with `gcc -c` but when I do `nvcc -c` I get compilation errors like:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(318): error: expected an identifier
```

Am I on a hiding to nothing trying to get code that refers to OpenMP to compile with nvcc? Forgive me if this is obvious but I'm new to CUDA. I'm using gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use such algorithms directly in device code anyway, so a typical suggestion is to separate your host code into portions that depend on this particular library, and portions that require CUDA.  Use function wrappers or what ever you like to connect the two.  Then compile your non-CUDA dependent modules with `g++`, and your CUDA dependent modules with `nvcc`.  Also, gcc 4.8.2 is not an officially supported platform for CUDA 5.5

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think I can include the library headers without pulling in <parallel/algorithm> but I do need other functionality in the library to run on the device. I'll have a look at using a different gcc as well.

Comment: "I do need other functionality in the library to run on the device".  If the library in question is a compiled library, it won't run on the device, unless you have the source code and can recompile it or it is a template library.  Even such libraries will require some effort to decorate properly for CUDA.  Furthermore, if said library elements depend in any way on STL elements, it likely won't be usable for device code.

Comment: The library is a header-only library and I know the authors have done some work to port it to CUDA. When I hit the problem and narrowed it down to the inclusion of `<parallel/algorithm>` I thought I'd ask here first. I'll try them directly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The new CUDA 6.5 RC toolkit [offers experimental support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/R37GIkMG4tk) for some c++11 features.

On Fedora20/gcc 4.8.2, CUDA 6.5RC, I was able to successfully compile the following code.

t1.cu:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <parallel/algorithm>

int main(){
}
```

using

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_20 t1.cu -o t1
```

You might check in your setup if just including `math.h` fixes the issue.  If not, moving forward to CUDA 6.5 may be worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for that. It doesn't fix it on CUDA 5.5.0 but I'll try and get 6.5 RC installed and test it there.